# How do these icicles seem to defy gravity and form in my ice cube tray in my freezer?

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-statics, ice

I've been seeing this effect in this particular freezer since we purchased it a couple of years ago and I finally want to know the answer.

In the picture below you can see that certain ice cubes will form an icicle even though this is just water poured into our ice cube trays.

[image: icicle in tray]

There is nothing above the the ice cube tray (just the top of the freezer) and it is about 8 inches away.  These are not formed by water dripping, but seem to be formed by water being pulled up and freezing?

Is this some form of static electricity at work?

Here's another snapshot from the side.

[image: icicle from side]

Comment: Just an intuition, the water condenses all about the ice, but the ones at the top have more trouble slipping down and freeze there. The ones on the sides sometimes freeze sometimes slip to the bottom. But according to another answer the water actually goes up! no idea why!

Comment: @JustJohan  I think that is the answer.  Although it seems to be a mystery to everyone.  Thanks.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny it is the analogous of the tip effect, replace electrical potential with chemical and you see it. Or just considering that ice grow on surface, and S/V is higher at the vertex. I am surprised that it always makes people curious, all crystals basically grow like that.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks!